# Convert local coordinates to scene coordinates in SceneKit

Tags: global, local, scenekit, coordinate

I have a node attached to a node and I want to convert it's coordinates to coordinates of scene. I really don't know how to do that. I've been searching on Apple's documentation and I haven't found a method that fits my need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SCNNode` exposes the following methods to convert between coordinate spaces:

```
-convertPosition:fromNode:
-convertPosition:toNode:
-convertTransform:fromNode:
-convertTransform:toNode:
```

Comment: This helps if you have the root node. If not, is there a better way than going up the node.parent tree until node.parent=nil to find the root?

Comment: `nil` is documented to be handled the same as the root node.